# How to tell when a jQuery UI sortable element is moved and in an invalid state

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two connect sortable lists.  I want to fire an event when an item is moved away from it's current list but NOT into the other connected list or when the item is being sorted.  Anyone know how to do that?

What I'm going for here is to have the user remove an item by dragging it away from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [Ian Wetherbee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214786/how-to-tell-when-a-jquery-ui-sortable-element-is-moved-and-in-an-invalid-state/3215065#3215065), you could also make the sortables droppable and use doppable's `out` and `over` events to track when the element is entering and exiting the area. Building on the [jQuery demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists), you could add functionality like this:

```
var isInside = true;

$("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    stop: function() { alert(isInside) }
})
.droppable({
    over: function() { isInside = true; },
    out: function() { isInside = false; },
    accept: "li"
});
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wy2AY/

Answer (score 3):

You can watch the `$(".selector").sortable({out: function(e, ui) {});` to set a variable whenever an object is dragged outside a list. If it is released then  `.sortable({stop: function(e, ui) {});` is triggered. You can tell if the object wasn't dropped on a list if  `.sortable({over: function(e, ui) {});` wasn't called after an `out` trigger.

Comment: I didn't get this to work this way. One case is when dragging one item directly out of the sortable (and not over the other sortable) and dropping it. The `out` callback won't be called and the variable isn't set correctly. I build by answer on your method, though, since `droppable`'s callbacks are called differently